# Setting Number of Threads in Distributed Testing in JMeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have to test an application with 1000 Users. For that, I have set up a load testing environment with 20 machines. Each Machine will generate a load of 50 VUsers.

So, I need a confirmation that the number that I will enter in '**No of Thread (Users)**' will be generated by all the slave machines. In my case, I should enter 50 and not 1000 here.

Comment: Rather than starting with 20 machines and 1000 users, you could run some tests of your test methods using two machines and 20 users per machine. Experiment with that and short duration (five or ten minutes) tests to learn how the test system behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in a distributed testing (master/slaves) environment, you have the option of configuring the slaves differently.  You start JMeter on the slaves manually, and then use the master to tell the slaves when to start sending requests to the server(s) being tested.  This [JMeter document](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) describes the distributed testing environment pretty well.

In your case, it sounds like you want the slaves to behave about the same, so setting the number of threads to 50 for each of the 20 slaves is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a confusion I had.